# Nginx: Can I `deny some-port` (not an IP) in a location?

Tags: nginx

In Nginx, can one somehow block or allow access from certain ports, in a `location`? Looking at [the allow & deny docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) it seems to me that they cannot be used for this purpose. Right? But is there no other way to do this?

---

Background:

In an Nginx virtual host, I'm allowing only a certain IP to publish websocket events:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /websocket/publish {
      allow 192.168.0.123;
      deny  all;
  }
```

However, soon the IP address of the appserver will we unknown, because everything will run inside Docker and I think I'll have no idea which ip a certain container will have.

So I'm thinking I could do this instead:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 81;

  location /websocket/publish {
      # Let the appserver publish via port 81.
      allow  :81;          # <–– "invalid parameter" error
      # Block everything else, so browsers cannot publish via port 80.
      deny  all;
  }

  ... other locations, accessible via port 80
```

And then have the firewall block traffic to port 81 from the outside world. But `allow :81` doesn't work. Is there no other way? Or am I on the wrong track; are there better ways to do all this?

(As far as I've understood from [the docs](https://nchan.slact.net/#conceptual-overview) about the websocket Nginx plugin I use (namely Nchan) I cannot add the `/websocket/publish` endpoint in another `server { }` block that listens on port 81 only.  **Edit:** Turns out I *can* just use different `server` blocks, because Nchan apparently ignores in which server block I place the config stuff, see: https://github.com/slact/nchan/issues/157. So I did that, works fine for me now. However would still be interesting to know if Nginx supports blocking a port in a `location { ... }`. )

Comment: You could just use separate server blocks that listen to different ports

Comment: @AlexeyTen Actually that's what I wrote about in the very last paragraph above — that I cannot do that. Because then Nchan won't realize that the publish & subscribe websocket endpoints belong to the same server, and then when I publish somehting, Nchan will think there are no subscribers (because they're in the wrong `server {}`). — But I might have misunderstood the Nchan docs, perhaps I should test & verify. I could contact the Nchan author and ask about this, and perhaps suggest a feature that makes many `server {}` possible

Comment: If you listen to different port you already have two servers for external client. It doesn't matter if you use one server block or two.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Are you saying that `server { listen 80; listen 81; ...stuff... }` is the same as `server { listen 80; ...stuff...} server { listen 81; ...stuff... }` ? If so, I had no idea. (I'm new to Nginx)

Comment: Yep. For client they're just server on port 80 and server on port 81.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Actually it wasn't a browser's point of view I had in mind, but rather an internal Nginx module named Nchan. I would think different Nginx modules treat `server` blocks in different ways. Nchan for one apparently ignores in which `server` block I place the config stuff, and instead has a directive `nchan_channel_group` that lets me group Nchan config stuff in any (?) way I want, apparently independent of `server` directives.

Comment: @AlexeyTen You were actually correct that I can just use separate server blocks, because the Nginx module I'm using, Nchan, apparently ignores in which `server` block I place the config stuff. (Here I posted & asked at Nchan @ GitHub: https://github.com/slact/nchan/issues/157  )